# How does the Javascript "this" operator deal with scopes?

Tags: javascript, scope, operators, this

**Edit:** I have to apologize, the problem I posted about actually does not exist in the code I posted, because I oversimplified it. I'll try to post something later.

Deletion would also be ok, but there are too many answers at present, so I cannot do it myself.

**Edit2:** Ok, here goes:

Let,

```
function F() {

    this.field = "value" ;

    var init = function(value) {
        this.field = value ;
    } ;

    this.method = function() {
        return this.field ;
    } ;

    init( arguments[0] ) ;

}
```

Now, instantiation of `F` type,

```
var f = new F("newValue") ;
```

will set the value to the `Window` object as `this` points to it when called from the closure.

Binding `this` to the `Function`,

```
function F() {

    var self = this ;

    this.field = "value" ;

    var init = function(value) {
        self.field = value ;
    } ;

    this.method = function() {
        return this.field ;
    } ;

    init( arguments[0] ) ;

}
```

will resolve the problem.

Still, what is the reason for this -- imho -- odd behaviour?

Comment: I'm kinda surprised this works at all.  Your functions are assigned to "var" variables, which should go away as soon as the function returns.  They never get attached to the object itself, so `f.method` would have no value (so by definition, it wouldn't be callable).

Comment: This might help explain it: http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/

Comment: @Brian: Who was that to?  It might help answer the question, but wouldn't explain why `f.method()` doesn't fail with errors about undefined values.

Comment: Indeed, this code doesn't work (`f.method is not a function`), so it's difficult to make any argument about how it works.

Comment: @ cHao: Typos. Check my update.

Comment: @ Brian Flanagan: Interesting link, thanks.

Comment: @FK82 well now your comment about the call to `f.method()` is incorrect - `this` will absolutely *not* point to the `window` object.

Comment: Your example works fine for me in Firefox. Both method calls return "someValue". Are you sure your example actually demonstrates how you're calling those functions? That makes a big different, as the value of "this" can change depending on the scope where the function was called.

Comment: this example works fine, I don't see the mystery.

Comment: @ mellowsoon, letronje: Spot on, I posted working code. :-) Will have to post something later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, this is one of the dark corners of the ECMA specification for ECMAScript (hence JavaScript):

> Finally a value is assigned for use with the this keyword. If the value assigned refers to an object then property accessors prefixed with the this keyword reference properties of that object. If the value assigned (internally) is null then the this keyword will refer to the global object.

(http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/ ; thanks to @ Brian Flanagan for the link)

Apparently, during execution of a function that is assigned to a variable (within another `Function`) the context is lost, the scope is thus set to null and `this` will refer to the `Window` `Object`.

---

I'm not quite sure whether this is something to expect from a `Function` initialized as a local variable. Typically I would expect a closure to have access to the scope it was created while that is still in memory, including it's predecessor in the scope chain.

This behaviour is different from a function that is the *property* of a `Function` `Object`, where the context is not lost and `this` will correctly point to the owner of the member `Function` (which is the `Function` `Object` or a member depending on how many layers there are).

---

The solution for this problem (while maintaining private `Function` members, i.e. members that are only accessible from within the `Function`'s scope) is wrapping the function inside another `Function` using `Function.prototype.apply` (or `Function.prototype.call`) to set the context manually:

```
function F() {

    this.field = "value" ;

    var self = this ;

    var init = function(value) {

        (function() {
            this.field = value ;
        }).apply(self,value) ;

    } ;

    this.method = function() {
        return this.field ;
    } ;

    init( arguments[0] ) ;

}
```

This is similar to `Function.prototype.bind` introduced in JavaScript 1.85 as well as the PrototypeJS library.

**Edit:** Forgot parentheses around the enclosed function in `init`. This will result in a `SyntaxError`.

Answer (score 2):

This is (a reference to) the object on which a function was called.

So in your `f.method()` call, `this` is "f". NOT "F".

The fact that `var self = this;` works is not due to this statement itself, but due to the fact that `method2()` is a **[closure](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/)**

To be more specific, the variable `self` inside `method2()` has a scope determined by `F()` - in other words, "self" inside `method2()` will ALWAYS refer o the value of `self` which existed when "F" was defined (which, at the time, was of course "F" since at that point current object context was "F").

Answer (score 1):

It's not correct to call `this` an "operator". It's an object reference established by the runtime upon function activation.

Javascript is just a different language that does things in different ways. That `this` is under control of the programmer is wonderfully powerful.

Also that code definitely does not work unless something else you didn't post is setting up a prototype object for "F". Neither "method" nor "method2" are callable from a reference to an instance of "F".

Comment: The MDC lists `this` under operators. Also, you don't really offer an explanation.

Comment: Apparently the MDC and I differ on the definition of "operator" :-)

Comment: It's indeed listed under "Operators" in the MDC reference, but the standard just calls it a "keyword", which I think is much more accurate.

Comment: @FK82 The `this` keyword is not an operator. It does not operate upon operands. It is just a keyword that references an object. The MDC should hire someone to proofread their stuff.

Comment: @ Šime Vidas, Pointy: I was just sticking to canonic definitions here. Personally, I call `this` a "keyword" as well.

Answer (score 1):

For the defining of method, you probably want to do something more like:

```
this.method = function()
{
    return this.field;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this the example you were looking for ?

```
var F = function() {

     var self = this ; //!! points correctly to the Function Object

     this.field = "someValue" ;

     var helper1 = function(){
         return self.field;
     }
     var helper2 = function(){
         return this.field;  
     } 
     this.method = function(){
         return helper1();
     }
     this.method2 = function(){
         return helper2();
     }
 }

 var f = new F() ;
     console.log(f.method()) ; 
     console.log(f.method2()) ;
```

In the case of method, it calls helper which uses self, which points to f when it gets created and hence it works.

In the case of method2, it uses helper2, which uses this. But the meaning of this while inside helper2 is the 'global' scope and hence returns undefined.